# Flagging posts as belonging to other Stack Exchange sites. (Not all Stack Exchange websites as an option)

Tags: discussion, bug, flags

When flagging a post on Stack Exchange because it belongs to another Stack Exchange site, the options for which site it belongs to doesn't include all the Stack Exchange sites.

For example, the post *[Code review request plus variable reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077570/code-review-request-plus-variable-reset)* can't be flagged as belonging to https://codereview.stackexchange.com, because it isn't an option while flagging it. There are only five Stack Exchange sites that are listed while flagging.